# Hyperlink gridview to another gridview

Tags: vb.net

Any simple example for:
When i click link in Table 1 and it will display to Table 2  (both table is on the same page. And table 2 is hidden)? Both tables have different data but both link based on Staff_ID.

Couldn't find any example for this in the internet.

UPDATE: i know how to link from table to next page. For example:

```
Protected Sub gvTable1_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles gvTable1.RowCommand

    Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
    Dim row As GridViewRow = gvTable1.Rows(index)

    Select Case e.CommandName
        Case "Select"
            Response.Redirect("profile?id=01&staffID=" & row.Cells(1).Text)
        Case Else
            'Do nothing
    End Select
End Sub
```

Right Now, just want to know how to link table to table on same page.

---

OKie, I figured it out:

```
Protected Sub gvTable1_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles gvTabel1.RowCommand
    Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
    Dim row As GridViewRow = gvTable1.Rows(index)
    Select Case e.CommandName
        Case "Select"
            txtTableID.Text = gvTable1.DataKeys(index).Value.ToString
            LoadGridTable2()
        Case Else
            'Do nothing
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If your simply hiding table2 (which I assume is a DataGridView), you could use:

```
DataGridView1.Visible = False
DataGridView2.Visible = True
```

and call it from your `DataGridView1` click event

Comment: Thanks for the share. i do know the code for hidden table. 
The only issue i had is to how to link table to table.